# Where does the Windows 8 Consumer Preview setup store its files?

Tags: windows-8-preview

Windows 8 Consumer Preview has been launched and I wanted to test it out. So I downloaded Windows 8 Consumer Preview Setup from http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/download.

But then I found that Win 8 is also available in `.iso` format. So I stopped the setup and started downloading the iso file. However, the Windows 8 setup had already allotted 2.8 GB of disk space. I want to free that space. What should I do?

I ran disk clean-up but nothing happened.

Where does the setup keeps the downloaded files?

Comment: It comes under windows ESD in the c windows folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it is downloading the files will be stored in `%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Websetup`

And after the download before the install you can find them in `C:\WindowsESD`

Comment: I finished the install, but the files were still there in the `C:\WindowsESD` folder. This was on Windows 7. Just FYI.

Answer (score 4):

The downloaded windows installation is stored here:

C:\ESD\Windows

Comment: This directory appears to be where the final Windows 8 installer places them.

Answer (score 3):

The [FAQ for the Win8 CP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/faq) mentions that it will download an installer optimized for your device. It also says that you *can't uninstall* it; you have to reinstall your original OS when you finish with the Preview. Just FYI.

I'm running the Windows 8 Consumer Preview Setup, watching it in Process Explorer. It appears to be using the following directory:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSetup\Panther\
```

However, I'm getting an error when I get to the download step, so I'm not seeing where the actual installer files are saved.

Comment: Got it going on a different system. There's a **Downloads** subdirectory of the one I listed above. On my system there's now a 2GB+ file in there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where the files are, but you could try [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) to look for folders containing about 2.8 GB that you don't think were there before and don't look like something important.

I'd suggest looking at the root of the system drive, or somewhere with the word "tmp", "temp" or "install" in the name, quite possibly a hidden folder.

Answer (score 2):

using [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/)...I found mine here (I stopped it before it completed to get the ISO)

`C:\Users\"YOUR USER NAME"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSetup\Download`

obviously you need your username